# Git clone hangs at "Retrieving object"

Tags: linux, git, kernel

As a prospective Linux developer I want to clone the git repositoy of Torvalds. The problem is when I call the git clone after some time the git clone process just hang. No error message no timeout nothing. So I press ctrl+c and I restart and again, same thing.

It hang at random percentage. It hang during the "Retrieving object" process.

Any idea someone?

Answer (score 3):

I saw something similar on a recent clone of a very large repository (working copy ~20 Gb).  Eventually, Git picked up again.  I'm not sure what was happening in my case exactly but it does seem as though the file system was thrashing.  Perhaps you could leave it hang for an hour or two to see if it comes back...

Hmmmmm, not exactly helpful, eh?

Comment: I've seen this in medium size repos, too, where the clone process is unresponsive for "too long." Sometimes the command line needs a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this question is better suited to #git on irc.freenode.net. Those people will be better equipped to help -- this is a troubleshooting situation that requires an interactive dialog, which StackOverflow is not extremely well suited for. Best of luck to you!